# Can i create any trigger on variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created one variable on page in start and I am calling one method whenever i do change that variable. I want to do something like if i assign new value to that variable and that method executes automaticaLLy. For code reference i am writing something below.

Well I don't want to write two lines every time like first for assigning value to variable and second line for calling method. I just want to write one line which is just for assignment to variable and it automatically execute that method.

Please help me.

```
  var SelectedUser = 0;

function LoadInformation()
{
    alert("Selected User is " + SelectedUser);
}

function UpdateSelectedUser(){
    SelectedUser = 5;
}
```

Comment: hello and welcome to stack overflow, you have many way to do this.. But to determine what is the best approch for you, could you please tell us if you use ES6 ? typescript ? ES5 ? do you have many case with same behavior ?

Comment: A setter could work: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use setters in javascript as follows:

```
var obj = {
  fooVal: 'this is the value of foo',
  get foo() {
      return this.fooVal;
  },
  set foo(val) {
      //here goes your trigger
      alert("trigger");
      this.fooVal = val;
  }
}

obj.foo = 'hello';//<=here goes your one line to set variable
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

**Use [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) object.**

> The Proxy object is used to define custom behavior for fundamental
>   operations (e.g. property lookup, assignment, enumeration, function
>   invocation, etc).

**Show me the code**

```js
var targetVariable = {};
var targetProxy = new Proxy(targetVariable, {
  set: function (target, key, value) {
      console.log('Value changed');
      target[key] = value;
      return true;
  }
});

targetProxy.hello_world = "test"; // console: 'value changed!!'
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using jQuery, you can easily trigger events and attach custom event listeners. For example you trigger `valueChanged` event each time you change the variable contents like this:

```js
var SelectedUser = 0;

$(document).on('valueChange', function() {
 alert("Selected User is " + SelectedUser);
})

function UpdateSelectedUser(){
    SelectedUser = 5;
    $('body').trigger('valueChange')
}

UpdateSelectedUser();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```